# How to send Personal Message using AJAX, PHP and MySQL?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to make a script, to send PM to user which is selected from MySQL.

I have users list:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fRZV.png

When I click PM button, I get Javascipt sceen:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bJ9A.png

How to fill-in Javascript screen fields with values from users list automatically and send values to other PHP file (with AJAX)?

Code of users list table:

```
        <!-- Table -->
        <table class="table table-condensed">
        <tr class="bg_h">
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th>Active?</th>
        <th>Registration date</th>
        <th>IP</th>
        <th>PM</th>
        </tr>

        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY user_id ASC";
        $query = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();
        $list = $query->fetchAll();

        foreach ($list as $row) {
        ?>
        <tr class="">
        <td><?php echo $row['user_name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['user_email']; ?></td>
        <td>
        <?php
        PHP code of getting user rank.
        ?>
        </td>
        <td>
        <?php
        PHP code to chech is user active.
        ?>
        </td>
        <td>
        <?php echo $row['user_registration_datetime']; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
        <?php echo $row['user_registration_ip']; ?>
        </td>           


        <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#send-pm">@PM</button>
        <div class="modal fade" id="send-pm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="send-pm-label" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="send-pm-label">Send personal message</h4>
        </div>    
        <div class="modal-body">        
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Receiver name</label>
        <textarea style="height:35px;" name="name" id="name" class="form-control"  ></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email" class="control-label">Email</label>
        <textarea style="height:35px;" name="email" id="email" class="form-control"  ></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="message" class="control-label">Message</label>
        <textarea style="height:250px;" name="message" id="message" class="form-control" ></textarea>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SEND</button>
        </div>    
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </table>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors with your current file? I'd recommend cleaning up your question and only provide the necessary code as I'm unable to figure out what issues you maybe having.

Comment: I don't know how to fill in AJAX textareas with Mysql values.


    <label for="name" class="control-label">Receiver name</label>
    <textarea style="height:35px;" name="name" id="name" class="form-control"  >SOMETHING HERE</textarea>

because, I get all users by foreach.

    foreach ($list as $row) {
    echo $row['user_name'];
    }

Comment: I think the question is missing the essential bit of code, which is the javascript that handles the PM button click event, and opens the modal dialog to send the message. It would be in this bit that you needed to get extract the username and email from the table row, and populate the relevant fields.

Comment: I edited the first post, section SEND FORM. I am using Bootstrap by the way and I use code from the website - http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

Comment: I'm not sure if the two-link limit for new users is a good idea. Nevertheless if you could avoid writing questions that hack around it, that would be appreciated - doing so just creates editing work for other users. Thanks! (The first image, being just tabular data, would be best added as text anyway, as it happens).

Comment: Your `AŽ` button doesn't seem to have a class to which you can attach a click event (so it can be differentiated from other `btn btn-primary` element types) and as @GarethD says, it needs a click handler. Can you work on that next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don`t need a modal dialog for every row in table. Take it out from the for-each loop. 
Also, add a class to every @PM button for easier selection. Aftewards, bind some actions to @PM button click event. Here is the code, be sure jquery is loaded.

```
 foreach ($list as $row) {
        ?>
        <tr class="">
            <td><?php echo $row['user_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['user_email']; ?></td>
            <td>
            <?php
            //PHP code of getting user rank.
            ?>
            </td>
            <td>
            <?php
            //PHP code to chech is user active.
            ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $row['user_registration_datetime']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $row['user_registration_ip']; ?>
            </td> 
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary data-grab-trigger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#send-pm">@PM</button>        
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        </table>
        <div class="modal fade" id="send-pm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="send-pm-label" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="send-pm-label">Send personal message</h4>
                        </div>    
                        <div class="modal-body">        
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name" class="control-label">Receiver name</label>
                        <textarea style="height:35px;" name="name" id="name" class="form-control"  ></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="email" class="control-label">Email</label>
                        <textarea style="height:35px;" name="email" id="email" class="form-control"  ></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="message" class="control-label">Message</label>
                        <textarea style="height:250px;" name="message" id="message" class="form-control" ></textarea>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                        <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">SEND</button>
                    </div>    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            $(function (){
                $('.data-grab-trigger').on('click', function (e) {
                    _email = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(0).text(); //get user email from the row where button was clicked
                    _name = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(1).text(); //get user name from the row where button was clicked

                    $("#email").val(_email);
                    $("#name").val(_name);
                });


            });
        </script>
```

Comment: I tried to apply your code but I failed. I updated my first post with information that is really necessary.

Comment: I still don`t see the table, only the form.